# How to unit test mock a mail sending function without sending mail python? I am using unittest.mock function

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am having trouble mocking the function. Even if I mock, it still sends an email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propagate a boolean "mock_if_true" and at the very last moment do not send the email. This is simple/stupid and OK as long as you do not have many such booleans.

**OR**: override the python class method (if you have one) to mock it

**OR**: consider separating the code building the email object from the code sending it. So you may easily test if the object is properly built.

Comment: There is a test function for which I am writing a unit test. TestFunction(). There is a different function which I am calling inside TestFunction to send a mail.